# Facebook connect comments

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to enable admin functionality for my facebook comment widget. I've included meta tags as required in the documentation but I still cannot delete other users messages.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{My Facebook ID}"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{My Application ID}"/>
```

and I am curious is it necessary to include this meta tags in the head of the document or can I put them in the body?

Also no comments appear in the comment moderation tool on the facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put them in the head. Also make sure you have the namespaces included:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/